# SurveyMonkey returning unexpected EOF error exchanging authorization code for access token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, surveymonkey, system.net.httpwebrequest

Code that had been working in a "localhost" environment is failing after deploying it to production under (obviously) a new callback URL.  Nothing else was changed.  The request to SurveyMonkey's API to exchange the Authorization Code for a long-lived Access Token is returning this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

Is there something else that needs to be changed, maybe to a production `client_id` ?  Please advise, we are stuck.

Here is the code:

```
        var clientId = _sds.ByName("SurveyMonkeyClientID").Value;
        var apiSecret = _sds.ByName("SurveyMonkeyAPISecret").Value;
        var callbackURL = _sds.ByName("SurveyMonkeyCallbackURL").Value;
        var accessTokenUri = "https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/token?api_key=" + _sds.ByName("SurveyMonkeyAPIKey").Value;

        // Create postback data
        var postData = new NameValueCollection()
        {
            { "client_secret", apiSecret },
            { "code", authorizationCode },
            { "redirect_uri", callbackURL },
            { "client_id", clientId },
            { "grant_type", "authorization_code" }
        };

        var queryString = string.Join("&", (
            from key in postData.AllKeys
            from value in postData.GetValues(key)
            select string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))).ToArray()
        );

        // Create and configure the web request object
        var request = WebRequest.Create(accessTokenUri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        var postArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
        dataStream.Write(postArray, 0, postArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        // Make the call to Survey Monkey's token exchange uri
        try
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            SaveSurveyMonkeyJsonWhole(responseFromServer);
            dynamic jobject = _serializer.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
            var access_token = jobject["access_token"];
            return access_token;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference on the SurveyMonkey side whether it's development or prod - so the error happens on calling out with a POST from the server hosting the callback URL?  Can it call out to SurveyMonkey's URLs otherwise?  Have you double checked the URL it's using?  Sounds like a connection issue to me.  You should always receive an error back from SurveyMonkey, not 0 bytes.

Comment: * Yes, the error occurs when we POST to SurveyMonkey. 
* The web server itself can navigate to https://api.surveymonkey.net.

Comment: Thanks for the response though, it is helpful to know SurveyMonkey always returns a response.  Since the URL is hard-coded that can't be it.  Even though it does seem like a connection issue, we can hit the API url from a browser on the web server directly and get an expected response.

Comment: If you're still stuck, email api-support@surveymonkey.com with the API key you're using so I can look into our logs for some ideas as to what is going wrong.

Comment: We are farely confident it is a proxy permission issue.  I will keep you updated.